Media Keys work on VLC but not on Chrome Browsers
My media keys (including Previous, Play/Pause, Next) work great in VLC under Kubuntu 24.04.1. I can load up an album and everything just works.
However, once I fire up a Youtube playlist in Chrome the only media key that will work for said playlist is Play/Pause. The Previous and Next keys don't function for the Youtube playlist. When I try this same thing in Windows 11 the Previous, Play/Pause and Next media keys work fine on a Youtube playlist.
I've changed the chrome://flags/ Hardware Media Key Handling flags to Default, Enabled, and Disabled but none of those options change anything. How do I get all my media keys to function on a Youtube playlist in a Chrome based browser?

you are silent on which version of kubuntu you are using but you may find this superuser post of interest

@graham I'm on Kubuntu 24.04.1. That post is helpful but I don't want to install any extensions and this is "supposed to" work out of the box since Chrome version 73 and I'm on Chrome version 128.
